# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, apache-axis

I work on a web application, I created a web service with axis2 I integrated this web service in my application, but the problem is that when I try to retrieve the wsdl via the following URL: http: / / localhost: 8080 / ConsoleSynoptique / services / listServices. I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1707)     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)      org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)      
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I work on the ide eclipse luna, Tomcat 7 as the application server.
The arboressebce application is:

```
C:.
│   .classpath
│   .project
│
├───.settings
│       .jsdtscope
│       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│       org.eclipse.wst.common.component
│       org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
│       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
│       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
│
├───build
│   └───classes
│       ├───fr
│       │   └───test
│       │       ├───si
│       │       │   └───sdvlesb1
│       │       │       └───meddiftopnotifiertops_ws_v1_amont_notifiertops
│       │       │               ArAnomalie$Factory.class
│       │       │               ArAnomalie.class
│       │       │               Notifier$Factory.class
│       │       │               Notifier.class
│       │       │               NotifierE$Factory.class
│       │       │               NotifierE.class
│       │       │               NotifierResponse$Factory.class
│       │       │               NotifierResponse.class
│       │       │               NotifierResponseE$Factory.class
│       │       │               NotifierResponseE.class
│       │       │               NotifierTopsV1MessageReceiverInOut.class
│       │       │               NotifierTopsV1Skeleton.class
│       │       │               PaireClefValeur$Factory.class
│       │       │               PaireClefValeur.class
│       │       │               Ping$Factory.class
│       │       │               Ping.class
│       │       │               PingE$Factory.class
│       │       │               PingE.class
│       │       │               PingResponse$Factory.class
│       │       │               PingResponse.class
│       │       │               PingResponseE$Factory.class
│       │       │               PingResponseE.class
│       │       │               UOM$Factory.class
│       │       │               UOM.class
│       │       │
│       │       └───soa
│       │           └───synoptique
│       │               ├───base
│       │               │       AccesConsoleSynoptique.class
│       │               │       IAccesConsoleSynoptique.class
│       │               │       Liste.class
│       │               │       Logueur.class
│       │               │       package-info.class
│       │               │       Parametre.class
│       │               │
│       │               ├───consolidation
│       │               │       ConsolidationIndicateurs.class
│       │               │       Historian.class
│       │               │       package-info.class
│       │               │       PurgeHistorian.class
│       │               │       ValeurIndicateur.class
│       │               │
│       │               ├───modele
│       │               │       Alarme.class
│       │               │       CompteurDeTentative.class
│       │               │       Etat.class
│       │               │       EtatString.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur$1.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur$2.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur$3.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur$4.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur$5.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur$6.class
│       │               │       FabriqueIndicateur.class
│       │               │       FabriqueJSON.class
│       │               │       FabriqueMetrique.class
│       │               │       Indicateur.class
│       │               │       IndicateurAlarme$SMTPAuthentificateur.class
│       │               │       IndicateurAlarme.class
│       │               │       Mesure.class
│       │               │       MesureAgregee.class
│       │               │       MesureElementAgrege.class
│       │               │       Metrique.class
│       │               │       ObjetMalforme.class
│       │               │       package-info.class
│       │               │       RapportDeSante.class
│       │               │       SerializableJSON.class
│       │               │       TypeAlarme.class
│       │               │       Variabilite.class
│       │               │
│       │               ├───serveur
│       │               │       Administration.class
│       │               │       AttributSession.class
│       │               │       Consignes.class
│       │               │       ConsoleSynoptique$1.class
│       │               │       ConsoleSynoptique.class
│       │               │       Consolidation.class
│       │               │       ControleAcces.class
│       │               │       Droits.class
│       │               │       EmetteurSSE.class
│       │               │       Evenements.class
│       │               │       FabriqueHTML.class
│       │               │       InitHttpServlet.class
│       │               │       package-info.class
│       │               │       Parametrage.class
│       │               │       Personnalisation.class
│       │               │       PileFifo.class
│       │               │       SupportJSPSEE.class
│       │               │       Surveillance.class
│       │               │
│       │               └───surveillance
│       │                       package-info.class
│       │                       SurveillanceAlarme.class
│       │                       SurveillanceBase.class
│       │                       SurveillanceComposantsSI.class
│       │                       SurveillanceGlobale.class
│       │                       SurveillanceNonEvenement.class
│       │                       SurveillanceSGBD.class
│       │                       SurveillanceWM.class
│       │
│       └───localhost
│           └───webservicestops
│               └───notifiertops_v1
│                       Contexte$Factory.class
│                       Contexte.class
│                       ETypeDuTop$Factory.class
│                       ETypeDuTop.class
│                       Exception$Factory.class
│                       Exception.class
│                       ExtensionMapper.class
│                       ReponseNotifier$Factory.class
│                       ReponseNotifier.class
│                       RequeteNotifier$Factory.class
│                       RequeteNotifier.class
│                       V1NotifierDonneesReponseNotifier$Factory.class
│                       V1NotifierDonneesReponseNotifier.class
│                       V1NotifierDonneesRequeteNotifier$Factory.class
│                       V1NotifierDonneesRequeteNotifier.class
│                       V1NotifierProgrammation$Factory.class
│                       V1NotifierProgrammation.class
│                       V1NotifierProgramme$Factory.class
│                       V1NotifierProgramme.class
│                       V1NotifierTop$Factory.class
│                       V1NotifierTop.class
│
├───lib
│   │   CsmControlerAccesUtilisateur.jar
│   │   CsmPinguerBusSOA.jar
│   │   CsmPinguerComposant.jar
│   │
│   └───ext
│           FwkSoatestV1R2.jar
│           ojdbc6.jar
│           sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar
│
├───src
│   ├───fr
│   │   └───test
│   │       ├───si
│   │       │   └───sdvlesb1
│   │       │       └───meddiftopnotifiertops_ws_v1_amont_notifiertops
│   │       │               ArAnomalie.java
│   │       │               Notifier.java
│   │       │               NotifierE.java
│   │       │               NotifierResponse.java
│   │       │               NotifierResponseE.java
│   │       │               NotifierTopsV1MessageReceiverInOut.java
│   │       │               NotifierTopsV1Skeleton.java
│   │       │               PaireClefValeur.java
│   │       │               Ping.java
│   │       │               PingE.java
│   │       │               PingResponse.java
│   │       │               PingResponseE.java
│   │       │               UOM.java
│   │       │
│   │       └───soa
│   │           └───synoptique
│   │               ├───base
│   │               │       AccesConsoleSynoptique.java
│   │               │       IAccesConsoleSynoptique.java
│   │               │       Liste.java
│   │               │       Logueur.java
│   │               │       package-info.java
│   │               │       Parametre.java
│   │               │
│   │               ├───consolidation
│   │               │       ConsolidationIndicateurs.java
│   │               │       Historian.java
│   │               │       package-info.java
│   │               │       PurgeHistorian.java
│   │               │       ValeurIndicateur.java
│   │               │
│   │               ├───modele
│   │               │       Alarme.java
│   │               │       CompteurDeTentative.java
│   │               │       Etat.java
│   │               │       FabriqueIndicateur.java
│   │               │       FabriqueJSON.java
│   │               │       FabriqueMetrique.java
│   │               │       Indicateur.java
│   │               │       IndicateurAlarme.java
│   │               │       Mesure.java
│   │               │       MesureAgregee.java
│   │               │       MesureElementAgrege.java
│   │               │       Metrique.java
│   │               │       ObjetMalforme.java
│   │               │       package-info.java
│   │               │       RapportDeSante.java
│   │               │       SerializableJSON.java
│   │               │       TypeAlarme.java
│   │               │       Variabilite.java
│   │               │
│   │               ├───serveur
│   │               │       Administration.java
│   │               │       AttributSession.java
│   │               │       Consignes.java
│   │               │       ConsoleSynoptique.java
│   │               │       Consolidation.java
│   │               │       ControleAcces.java
│   │               │       Droits.java
│   │               │       EmetteurSSE.java
│   │               │       Evenements.java
│   │               │       FabriqueHTML.java
│   │               │       InitHttpServlet.java
│   │               │       package-info.java
│   │               │       Parametrage.java
│   │               │       Personnalisation.java
│   │               │       PileFifo.java
│   │               │       SupportJSPSEE.java
│   │               │       Surveillance.java
│   │               │
│   │               └───surveillance
│   │                       package-info.java
│   │                       SurveillanceAlarme.java
│   │                       SurveillanceBase.java
│   │                       SurveillanceComposantsSI.java
│   │                       SurveillanceGlobale.java
│   │                       SurveillanceNonEvenement.java
│   │                       SurveillanceSGBD.java
│   │                       SurveillanceWM.java
│   │
│   └───localhost
│       └───webservicestops
│           └───notifiertops_v1
│                   Contexte.java
│                   ETypeDuTop.java
│                   Exception.java
│                   ExtensionMapper.java
│                   ReponseNotifier.java
│                   RequeteNotifier.java
│                   V1NotifierDonneesReponseNotifier.java
│                   V1NotifierDonneesRequeteNotifier.java
│                   V1NotifierProgrammation.java
│                   V1NotifierProgramme.java
│                   V1NotifierTop.java
│
└───WebContent
    │   Aide.png
    │   Alarme.mp3
    │   Avant.png
    │   Avertissement.mp3
    │   Consignes.jsp
    │   Consignes.png
    │   Consignes25x25.png
    │   Console-Copy.jsp
    │   Console.html
    │   Console.html.bak
    │   Console.jsp
    │   ConsoleBG.html
    │   ConsoleNew.jsp
    │   ContexteGeneral.mp3
    │   EtatSynoptiqueSOA.jsp
    │   Evenements.jsp
    │   Evenements.png
    │   Evenements25x25.png
    │   GardienDeSession.jsp
    │   index.html
    │   index.jsp
    │   Interdit.html
    │   Interdit.jsp
    │   logo.png
    │   Parametrage.html
    │   Parametrage.jsp
    │   Parametre.png
    │   Parametre25x25.png
    │   Personnalisation.jsp
    │   Personnalisation.png
    │   Personnalisation25x25.png
    │   Retour.png
    │   SupportConsole.js
    │
    ├───aide
    │   │   AffichageConsoleSynoptique.html
    │   │
    │   └───AffichageConsoleSynoptique_fichiers
    │           filelist.xml
    │           image001.png
    │           image002.gif
    │           image003.png
    │           image004.gif
    │           image005.gif
    │           image006.gif
    │           image006.png
    │           image008.png
    │           image010.png
    │           image011.gif
    │           image011.png
    │           image012.gif
    │           image012.png
    │           image013.gif
    │           image013.png
    │           image014.png
    │           image015.gif
    │           image015.png
    │           image016.png
    │           image017.gif
    │           image017.png
    │           image018.png
    │           image019.jpg
    │           image020.jpg
    │           image020.png
    │           image021.jpg
    │           image022.jpg
    │           image026.jpg
    │           image027.jpg
    │           oledata.mso
    │
    ├───axis2-web
    │   │   ActivateService.jsp
    │   │   admin.jsp
    │   │   deleteService.jsp
    │   │   disengage.jsp
    │   │   EngageToServiceGroup.jsp
    │   │   engagingglobally.jsp
    │   │   engagingtoanoperation.jsp
    │   │   engagingtoaservice.jsp
    │   │   error.jsp
    │   │   errorModule.jsp
    │   │   globalModules.jsp
    │   │   HappyAxis.jsp.old
    │   │   InActivateService.jsp
    │   │   index.jsp
    │   │   LeftFrame.jsp
    │   │   listFaultyService.jsp
    │   │   listGroupService.jsp
    │   │   listModules.jsp
    │   │   listService.jsp
    │   │   ListServiceGroup.jsp
    │   │   listServices.jsp
    │   │   listSingleService.jsp
    │   │   Login.jsp
    │   │   MainFrame.jsp
    │   │   SelectService.jsp
    │   │   ServiceParaEdit.jsp
    │   │   TopFrame.jsp
    │   │   upload.jsp
    │   │   ViewContexts.jsp
    │   │   ViewGlobalHandlers.jsp
    │   │   viewphases.jsp
    │   │   viewServiceContext.jsp
    │   │   viewServiceGroupContext.jsp
    │   │   ViewServiceHandlers.jsp
    │   │
    │   ├───css
    │   │       axis-style.css
    │   │
    │   ├───Error
    │   │       AuthError.html
    │   │       error404.jsp
    │   │       error500.jsp
    │   │       GenError.html
    │   │
    │   ├───images
    │   │       asf-logo.gif
    │   │       axis.gif
    │   │       axis.jpg
    │   │       axis_l.jpg
    │   │
    │   └───include
    │           adminfooter.inc
    │           adminheader.inc
    │           adminheader.jsp
    │           footer.inc
    │           header.inc
    │           httpbase.jsp
    │           link-footer.inc
    │           link-footer.jsp
    │
    ├───META-INF
    │       MANIFEST.MF
    │
    └───WEB-INF
        │   web.xml
        │
        ├───classes
        │   │   commons-logging.properties
        │   │   log4j.properties
        │   │
        │   ├───META-INF
        │   │       LICENSE
        │   │       NOTICE
        │   │
        │   └───org
        │       └───apache
        │           └───axis2
        │               ├───transport
        │               │   └───http
        │               │           AxisAdminServlet.class
        │               │
        │               └───webapp
        │                       AdminAgent.class
        │                       AxisAdminServlet.class
        │
        ├───conf
        │       axis2.policy
        │       axis2.xml
        │       commons-logging.properties
        │       Configuration.xml
        │       ConfigurationDefaut.xml
        │       Configuration_Dev.xml
        │       Configuration_Prod.xml
        │       Consignes.txt
        │       Evenements.txt
        │       testSoaFwk.properties
        │       testSoaFwkControlerAccesUtilisateur.properties
        │       testSoaFwkPinguerBusSOA.properties
        │       testSoaFwkPinguerComposant.properties
        │       log4j.properties
        │       PersonnalisationDefaut.xml
        │       Personnalisationll.xml
        │       Personnalisationvisu.xml
        │
        ├───historian
        │   │   CreationBD.sql
        │   │   css - Copie.db3
        │   │   css.db3
        │   │   CSS_TE_INDICATEUR.sql
        │   │
        │   └───old
        │           css - Copie.db3
        │           css.db3
        │
        ├───lib
        │       activation-1.1.jar
        │       activation-LICENSE.txt
        │       antlr-2-LICENSE.txt
        │       antlr-2.7.7.jar
        │       apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
        │       apache-mime4j-core-LICENSE.txt
        │       axiom-api-1.2.13.jar
        │       axiom-api-LICENSE.txt
        │       axiom-dom-1.2.13.jar
        │       axiom-dom-LICENSE.txt
        │       axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar
        │       axiom-impl-LICENSE.txt
        │       axis2-adb-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-adb-codegen-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-ant-plugin-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-clustering-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-codegen-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-corba-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-fastinfoset-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-java2wsdl-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-jaxbri-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-jaxws-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-jibx-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-json-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-LICENSE.txt
        │       axis2-metadata-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-mtompolicy-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-saaj-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-soapmonitor-servlet-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-spring-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-transport-local-1.6.2.jar
        │       axis2-xmlbeans-1.6.2.jar
        │       bcel-5.1.jar
        │       bcel-LICENSE.txt
        │       commons-cli-1.2.jar
        │       commons-cli-LICENSE.txt
        │       commons-codec-1.3.jar
        │       commons-codec-LICENSE.txt
        │       commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
        │       commons-fileupload-LICENSE.txt
        │       commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
        │       commons-httpclient-LICENSE.txt
        │       commons-io-1.4.jar
        │       commons-io-LICENSE.txt
        │       commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
        │       commons-logging-LICENSE.txt
        │       FwkSoatestV1R2.jar
        │       geronimo-annotation-LICENSE.txt
        │       geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.jar
        │       geronimo-jaxws-LICENSE.txt
        │       geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar
        │       geronimo-jta-LICENSE.txt
        │       geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
        │       geronimo-saaj-LICENSE.txt
        │       geronimo-saaj_1.3_spec-1.0.1.jar
        │       geronimo-stax-api-LICENSE.txt
        │       geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
        │       geronimo-ws-metadata-LICENSE.txt
        │       geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
        │       httpcore-4.0.jar
        │       httpcore-LICENSE.txt
        │       jalopy-1.5rc3.jar
        │       jalopy-LICENSE.txt
        │       jaxb-api-2.1.jar
        │       jaxb-api-LICENSE.txt
        │       jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar
        │       jaxb-impl-LICENSE.txt
        │       jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar
        │       jaxb-xjc-LICENSE.txt
        │       jaxen-1.1.1.jar
        │       jaxen-LICENSE.txt
        │       jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar
        │       jaxws-tools-LICENSE.txt
        │       jettison-1.0-RC2.jar
        │       jettison-LICENSE.txt
        │       jibx-bind-1.2.jar
        │       jibx-bind-LICENSE.txt
        │       jibx-run-1.2.jar
        │       jibx-run-LICENSE.txt
        │       jsr311-api-1.0.jar
        │       jsr311-api-LICENSE.txt
        │       juli-6.0.16.jar
        │       juli-LICENSE.txt
        │       log4j-1.2.15.jar
        │       log4j-LICENSE.txt
        │       mail-1.4.jar
        │       mail-LICENSE.txt
        │       mex-1.6.2-impl.jar
        │       neethi-3.0.2.jar
        │       neethi-LICENSE.txt
        │       regexp-1.2.jar
        │       regexp-LICENSE.txt
        │       tribes-6.0.16.jar
        │       tribes-LICENSE.txt
        │       woden-api-1.0M9.jar
        │       woden-api-LICENSE.txt
        │       woden-impl-commons-1.0M9.jar
        │       woden-impl-commons-LICENSE.txt
        │       woden-impl-dom-1.0M9.jar
        │       woden-impl-dom-LICENSE.txt
        │       wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
        │       wsdl4j-LICENSE.txt
        │       wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar
        │       wstx-LICENSE.txt
        │       xalan-2.7.0.jar
        │       xalan-LICENSE.txt
        │       xml-resolver-1.2.jar
        │       xml-resolver-LICENSE.txt
        │       xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
        │       xmlbeans-LICENSE.txt
        │       XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
        │       XmlSchema-LICENSE.txt
        │
        ├───modules
        │       addressing-1.6.2.mar
        │       mex-1.6.2.mar
        │       modules.list
        │       mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
        │       ping-1.6.2.mar
        │       scripting-1.6.2.mar
        │       soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
        │
        └───services
            │   services.list
            │   version.aar
            │
            └───NotifierTopsV1
                ├───fr
                │   └───test
                │       └───si
                │           └───sdvlesb1
                │               └───meddiftopnotifiertops_ws_v1_amont_notifiertops
                │                       ArAnomalie$Factory.class
                │                       ArAnomalie.class
                │                       Notifier$Factory.class
                │                       Notifier.class
                │                       NotifierE$Factory.class
                │                       NotifierE.class
                │                       NotifierResponse$Factory.class
                │                       NotifierResponse.class
                │                       NotifierResponseE$Factory.class
                │                       NotifierResponseE.class
                │                       NotifierTopsV1MessageReceiverInOut.class
                │                       NotifierTopsV1Skeleton.class
                │                       PaireClefValeur$Factory.class
                │                       PaireClefValeur.class
                │                       Ping$Factory.class
                │                       Ping.class
                │                       PingE$Factory.class
                │                       PingE.class
                │                       PingResponse$Factory.class
                │                       PingResponse.class
                │                       PingResponseE$Factory.class
                │                       PingResponseE.class
                │                       UOM$Factory.class
                │                       UOM.class
                │
                ├───localhost
                │   └───webservicestops
                │       └───notifiertops_v1
                │               Contexte$Factory.class
                │               Contexte.class
                │               ETypeDuTop$Factory.class
                │               ETypeDuTop.class
                │               Exception$Factory.class
                │               Exception.class
                │               ExtensionMapper.class
                │               ReponseNotifier$Factory.class
                │               ReponseNotifier.class
                │               RequeteNotifier$Factory.class
                │               RequeteNotifier.class
                │               V1NotifierDonneesReponseNotifier$Factory.class
                │               V1NotifierDonneesReponseNotifier.class
                │               V1NotifierDonneesRequeteNotifier$Factory.class
                │               V1NotifierDonneesRequeteNotifier.class
                │               V1NotifierProgrammation$Factory.class
                │               V1NotifierProgrammation.class
                │               V1NotifierProgramme$Factory.class
                │               V1NotifierProgramme.class
                │               V1NotifierTop$Factory.class
                │               V1NotifierTop.class
                │
                └───META-INF
                        NotifierTopsV1.wsdl
                        services.xml
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The application is trying to use the class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet but it can't find it.  This class can be found in the servlet-api-x.x.jar.  Try adding that jar to your classpath.  Here is the link to [where you can obtain it with maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0).

Comment: thank you very much it works wonderfully.
I used javax.servlet-api.jar because javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar returned an error.

Answer (score 1):

for those who are interested, it is trying to call the web service from soapUI, I got the following error:

java.lang.LinkageError: org / apache / axiom / soap / SOAPEnvelope

and to solve it I delete all the lib from  /web-inf/lib